# Django integration with JS

Tags: javascript, django

I am working in a Django app that must show an interactive visualization of different .stl files. I am using Madeleine.js and the problem is that just the last one appear.

I have a principal .html with this loop:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for piece in pieces %}

            {% include "element/element_card.html" %}

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And inside the element_card.html this div tag:

```
<div id="target" class="madeleine container"></div>
```

A js file is called from element_card.html in order to create the visualization inside this `div id="target"`.

Comment: With your code, all the cards have the same `id`, this can be the problem

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to change the id for each card (they are generated automatically with data from the db) and change the id in the js file to match them.

Comment: if it is ok for you to have Id's like 'target-0', 'target-1' and so on in your base template use de `{% with` template tag, just encapsulate your `include` and use the `forloop.counter`, something like `{% with id_count=forloop.counter %}{% include ... %}{% endwith %}`

And in your element_card.html use something like `id="target-{{id_count}}"`

Comment: Thanks, it is a solution.